# How to solve the error: "no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>" when std::bind is used in a class

Tags: c++, stl

Usually, std::bind works well in boost::math::tools::bisect(). However, when I tried to use std::bind in a class with member functions, there is always error:

> no matching function for call to `bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>` ...

This is one member function of the class:

```
double SingleCapillaryTube::calLocationFunctionWithoutAngle(const TubeGeometry &TG,
                                const FluidProperties &FP, double tempLocation,
                                double initialLocationValue, double tempTime,
                                const double initialTimePoint)
{
    auto coefficientB = calCoefficientB(TG, FP);
    auto coefficientA = calCoefficientA(TG, FP);
    auto coefficientD = calCoefficientD(TG, FP);
    auto tempValue = -coefficientB * (tempLocation - initialLocationValue) - \
                    1./2. * coefficientA * (pow(tempLocation, 2.) - \
                    pow(initialLocationValue, 2.)) - coefficientD * \
                    (tempTime - initialTimePoint);
    return tempValue;
}
```

Then this function is used in the other member function of the class:

```
void SingleCapillaryTube::calLocationInterfaceBisect()
{
    stepResult = boost::math::tools::bisect(
                std::bind(calLocationFunctionWithAngle,\
                Geometry, Fluids, _3, initialLocation, \
                timePoint, initialTime), 0.0, \
                -Geometry.length, Tol);
}
```

When the file was compiled, the error always occurred. Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide a [**minimal**, complete, and **verifiable** example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should be able to reduce this down *a lot*.

Comment: Is compiler is upgrade to c++11? I think  std::bind is supported from 11.

Comment: Yes, it is compiled with c++11. I have compiled several simple examples and they works. The error only happened when it was used in a class.

Comment: Why on Earth do you put backslashes at the end of the line?! It's totally unnecessary (the only use in C++ is when you have long macros, which you should try to avoid anyway).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Non-static member functions need an instance to be called on.  To give it that, pass your `this` pointer as the first argument to the function.  You also need to use the full qualified name of the function and take its address:

```
std::bind(&SingleCapillaryTube::calLocationFunctionWithAngle, this,
          Geometry, Fluids, _3, initialLocation, timePoint, initialTime)
```

Also note that using `_3` binds the third positional argument to that parameter, so in this case the first and second arguments will be ignored.  You likely want `_1` in that spot.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice, Miles:) but after 'this' is added, the error is still there......

Comment: You're right, I missed the other issue.  I've edited my post.  Hopefully that fixes your problem.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please click the little checkmark next to the question to mark this as the accepted answer.